# HOW TO HIJACK calls to a class::function in PHP (osTicket)

Tags: php, scripting

In osTicket, there is a class DynamicList::getItems() function, in file class.list.php. I am looking to intercept all calls to this function and add code to the start of it, before the rest of the function commands are executed.

The class is of course not my own but of the osTicket core and I want to avoid altering core files for obvious reasons. I have no idea how to do this. All help is appreciated.

**UPDATE1:**

this file is require_once by 4 files in osTicket:
\include\class.dynamic_forms.php(21): require_once(INCLUDE_DIR . 'class.list.php');
\include\class.search.php(25): require_once INCLUDE_DIR . 'class.list.php';
\include\upgrader\streams\core\9143a511-0d6099a6.task.php(11):         require_once(INCLUDE_DIR . 'class.list.php');
\scp\lists.php(3): require_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.list.php');

**UPDATE2:**

1. I have changed the name of the file 'class.list.php' to
   'class.list.php.core.php'
2. I have changed the definition'class DynamicList' ->
   'class DynamicListCore' (in above file)
3. I have created a new file
   'class.list.php'
4. I added in this file the folowing:

> ```
> require_once(INCLUDE_DIR .'class.list.php.core.php');
> class DynamicList extends DynamicListCore {
>      ... my stuff
>      return(DynamicListCore::getItems($limit=false, $offset=false));
> }
> ```
>
> Works pretty good. But I had to change the content of the core file. Can I do it in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did it my way like this:

1. I have changed the name of the file 'class.list.php' to
   'class.list.php.core.php'
2. I have changed the definition'class DynamicList' ->
   'class DynamicListCore' (in above file)
3. I have created a new file
   'class.list.php'
4. I added in this file the folowing:

> ```
> require_once(INCLUDE_DIR .'class.list.php.core.php');
> class DynamicList extends DynamicListCore {
>      ... my stuff
>      return(DynamicListCore::getItems($limit=false, $offset=false));
> }
> ```
>
> Works pretty good. But I had to change the content of the core file by adding 4 characters to 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the class and override the method to add your own content and call the parent method :

```
<?php
// The base class you don't want to modify
class foo
{
    public function Hello()
    {
        echo "World";
    }
}

// Your class created to add extensions
class bar extends foo
{
    public function Hello()
    {
        echo "Hello ";
        parent::Hello(); // call the base method
    }
}

$obj = new bar();

$obj->Hello();
```

This outputs `Hello World`

Comment: Yes but would I need to modify the same core file class.list.php, in order to add the class bar extends foo? Where to I add this extension to make sure it is always relevant no matter who calls class foo (without modifying the core file)?

Comment: You'll have to define that new class and use it instead of `DynamicList`. This is the only way I know to add features to a method without modifying the original one

Comment: But DynamicList::getItems() could be called from 10 or 20 places in osTicket. That would mean I have to find all these places and modify them to call bar instead of foo!!! that means I modify the core. right?

Comment: If that's for internal usage of `osTicket` only, you can't alter the behaviour without modifying it, AFAIK

Comment: All core files were written by osTicket for osTicket and not meant for modification by users. However, if there is a way for me to somehow define my new class as an extension for their class in one place (e.g. an include or a require), where it will take on global override for the whole of osTicket, then this is what I want.

Comment: I have an idea... maybe if I replace their file with my own file? Whenever an upgrade happens, I can remember to just replace their class.list.php with mine. What do you think?